# Ajax page onclick doesn't work when function defined in $(function(){ })

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

define two functions like this:

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            function testb() {
                alert("ddd");
            }
        })

        function testa() {
            alert("ddd");
        }
    </script>
```

when page loaded show an ajax page, then call thoese functions from an ajax page, `testa` will be successful called but not `testb`.

Comment: `testb()` is defined inside ready handler scope

Comment: You wrapped `testb` definition within another function, it is not visible outside.

Comment: good to know that

Comment: could you please share you Ajax code as well?

Comment: have a search for javascript scoped variables - same applies to functions.  As you have testb in a closure, it's only available to items within the closure.  Is there any reason you wrapped it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: @CodeFarmer, please check my answer.. it will work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your function is inside the document.ready then you will be able to call global functions as well in ajax success. if your ajax call is in global. then you will not be able to call a function inside document.ready. because of scope limitations..

samples: Ajax inside document.ready

```
 function testb() {
    alert('ddd');
}
$(function () {

    $('[id$=btnsubmit]').on('click', function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/Content/test",
            success: function (data) {
                // alert(data);
                testa();
                testb();
            }
        });

    });
    function testa() {
        alert('zxfgsfg');
    }
});
```

it will work..

IF Still you want to call that function in that way, please check below solution:

```
    function tesss() {
    alert('ddd');
}

var M7 = {};

$('[id$=btnsubmit]').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/Content/test",
        success: function (data) {
            // alert(data);
            M7();
            tesss();
        }
    });

});
$(function () {
    M7 = function () {
        alert('zxfgsfg');
    };
});
```

Comment: in my case, i don't need call any function after ajax success. what i want to do is use ajax load a html page, then use onclick inside this page to call a function, i just don't know why it's work only when function is alone.